# MySQL select unique records on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select rows where two columns are unique?

Given table

```
id    col1   col2
1     a      222
2     b      223
3     c      224
4     d      224
5     b      225
6     e      226
```

How do remove the duplicates in col1 and the duplicates in col2, to get rows unique to whole table, 
So that result is

```
id   col1   col2
1    a      222
6    e      226
```

Is there a better way than using sub queries?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id 
  IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE col1 
        IN (SELECT col1 FROM table GROUP BY col1 HAVING(COUNT(col1)=1))
        GROUP BY col2 HAVING(COUNT(col2)=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work using `exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable y
where not exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y2
  where y.id != y2.id
    and (y.col1 = y2.col1 
    or y.col2 = y2.col2))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5df76/1)

---

Here's an alternative solution using an `outer join` as I've read mysql sometimes doesn't do well with `exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable y
  left join yourtable y2 on y.id != y2.id
    and (y.col1 = y2.col1 
    or y.col2 = y2.col2)
where y2.id is null;
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5df76/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by aggregating along each dimension:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select col1
      from table t
      group by col1
      having count(*) = 1
     ) t1
     on t.col1 = t1.col1 join
     (select col2
      from table t
      group by col2
      having count(*) = 1
     ) t2
     on t.col2 = t2.col2;
```

This method seems like a very direct translation of the user requirements.